# CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE option in libcurl c code

Tags: bash, curl

What curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "") this line of c code means in curl and how can I write equivalent command in command line

Code-

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "")
```

Equivalent code in command line-

```
 curl -c ?? something like this
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libcurl reads file CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE for cookies and send it to server with request

this will be:

```sh
curl -b filename
```

or

```sh
curl -b cookie1=value1
```

`curl -c` - it is a cookie jar, which is used for storing received data from response